# Comparison of regexp_replace and regexp_substr variables

Tags: sql, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

I have a problem comparing variants.

When I perform a query in the database using the expressions `regexp_replace` and `regexp_substr` I get my expected result and insert into a variable created in the procedure.

```
SELECT SUBSTR (regexp_substr (regexp_replace (ds_text_macro, '<. *?>'), '@ [^.] *'), Macro_files_w, macro_files_final_w - 1) ds_macro
into retorno_filha_macro_w
FROM config_imp_sumario
WHERE ie_type_summary = 'RESU'
AND upper (ds_macro_reference) LIKE '%' || upper (return_macro_w) || '%';
```

The variable `return_film_macro_w` is given the value "**@blood_pressure**".
When I try to compare this variable with a field in a table that has the same value it does not find anything.

Entering the non-variable direct value works correctly.

Why I can not compare this type of variable?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

[Procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyFhI.jpg)

See if it's clearer please!

In this procedure I'm just getting the values of some xml tags.
And doing the comparison with the table res_resultado_patient.

The variable return_files_macro_w returns me '@blood_pressure' and the ds_macro_references field of the res_patient table also returns me '@blood_pressure', but the cursor does not find any information.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPm10.jpg)